# Prononciation de « clinker »

Tags: prononciation, anglicismes

La prononciation suivante de « [clinker](https://fr.howtopronounce.com/french/clinker) » comporte un « \e\ » à la fin. La prononciation de « in » est comme d'habitude (\klɛ̃ke). On pourrait dire que c'est un mot dont la prononciation est totalement francisée.

On trouve ensuite la prononciation anglaise légèrement francisée dans l'audio de la source suivante mais la transcription phonétique est celle de la prononciation précédente (\klɛ̃ke).

[clinker](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/clinker)

Le Wiktionnaire donne deux  variantes : «  [\klin.kœʁ\ ou \klɛ̃.kɛʁ\](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/clinker)  ».

C'est un mot qui n'est pas porté au TLFi, ni dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie.

Finalement, quelle devrait être la prononciation de ce mot ? \klɛ̃ke ? \klin.kœʁ\ ? \klɛ̃.kɛʁ\ ? Ou peut-être \klin.kɛʁ\ ? Quel est le système en vigueur pour ce type de mot (emprunt de l'anglais) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De ce que j'ai trouvé, en France on prononce \klɛ̃.kɛʁ\, et au Québec \klin.kœʁ\, plus proche de la prononciation anglaise. (Source : [plusieurs](https://youtu.be/04anUQHXbLM) [vidéos](https://youtu.be/AVNQIRRD35s?t=70) trouvées sur youtube expliquant la fabrication du charbon)

La prononciation \klɛ̃.kɛʁ\ est assez logique étant donné que le mot est un emprunt assez ancien (d'après [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clinker&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3), le mot est usité dès 1900).

De ce que j'ai observé, les emprunts "anciens" ont tendance à prononcer autant à la française que possible, avec les mots en -er prononcés \ɛʁ\ (comme dans *boxer*, *water-polo*, ou même le cirque *Pinder*), alors qu'à partir des années 80-90 on observe plutôt des anglicismes qui tendent à se rapprocher de la prononciation anglaise.

C'est une observation personnelle et je n'ai pas de source à part une collection d'exemples, mais je trouve assez peu de contre-exemples.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu que /klinkœr/ et /klinkɛr/ en Belgique, voire /klinkœrs/ avec la désinence du pluriel conservée, mais jamais de version avec voyelle nasale (c'est habituel avec les emprunts à l'anglais, on évite généralement toujours les voyelles nasales)

Comment: Ceci dit, je confonds probablement le clinker (composant du ciment), que je n'ai jamais entendu prononcé, avec les pavés klinkers qui eux sont bien /klinkœrs/ de manière consistente

Answer (score 1):

*Clinker* est un mot que je n'ai jamais eu l'occasion de prononcer moi-même, mais dans mon travail d'interprète j'ai entendu les deux prononciations données par le Wiktionnaire.

Par contre, je n'ai jamais entendu la prononciation \klɛ̃ke\.